# Link in header bar not automaticly formatted as button?

Tags: jquery, css, jquery-mobile

Is there a way to use my own image/text without it being automaticly formatted as a button in a header-bar?

I'm Using jQueryMobile RC 1.0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just found the solution in reading the uncompressed javascript files.

I need to add `data-role="none"` to my HTML a tag.